# mongodb inner loop on same collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am looking for a query that finds documents that lower than the specific date and also will give me the row that has a ref key equals to that id

for the following data (1 collection)  and the date param is "01-10-2019" (Oct 2019):(so will search first only
lte : 01-10-2020

```
   {
     {
      "id": 1, 
      "ref": null,
      "date": "20-09-2020" (SEP 20)
    },
    {
      "id": 2, 
      "ref": 1,
      "date": "today"
    },
    {
      "id": 3, 
      "ref" null,
       "date": "today"
    
    }
}
```

the result will be : `id 1 and 2` , because `1` is meet the date criteria and id `2` has ref key that equal to id `1`.
id `3` won't be received because it's not meet the date criteria

```
   {
     {
      "id": 1, 
      "ref": 2,
      "date": "one month before"
    },
    {
      "id": 2, 
      "ref": 1,
      "date": "today"
    },
 
}
```

the issue is that I need to go on above 100-200k rows and every time work on let's say 1000 docs

how can I do that in an efficient way?

I thought about something like:
1-

```
 col.find({date:{$lte:given_Date}}
```

2- run on each of the result and find

```
 col.findOne({ref:given_id}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `aggregation framework`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {//Add a field to convert your dates
      "date1": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$date",
              "today"
            ]
          },
          "then": new Date(),
          "else": {
            "$toDate": "$date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {//Join
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "ref",
      "as": "output"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {//match condition
      "date1": {
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-10-01T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  }
])
```

1. Store a proper date than string format
2. Do not find current day by today - how do you change it when day passes!!
3. If the above two suggestions incorporated, you could avoid `$addFields`.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BcqsVYw-U3L)

Comment: @gibs 

Hi thanks
how can I return only docs that they are can be in "ref" column but only for docs their data I meet the criteria  

lets say in that case "id" 1 will not be returned because the id 2 "date" is newer thaan lets say "01-12-2020"

Comment: here
https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZN4qCkXceAw

can you take a look in the comments in the left side
so i want return only ids that meet the date criteria and also if some docs uses those id as ref they wont be returned

Comment: I ll check this and come back soon